# favicon.ico not shown on IE [Worked in Chrome & FireFox]

Tags: internet-explorer, fiddler, favicon

As per question, I was unable to display the favicon.ico on IE. (The project is deployed on Apache Tomcat 7.0 and tested on IE 10)

**Note: I can only deploy the favicon.ico inside my project folder and no where else. Solution like "deploy at the ROOT directory" or "deploy on a web server" doesn't help for me.**

I have declare the icon in my .jsp as following:

```
<link rel="icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" >
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" >
```

I have also try the following and it still won't work.

```
<link rel="icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="../images/favicon.ico"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico"/>
```

After browsing through some help, i saw some forum mention about using **fiddler** to determine whether the request was make and this is what i got:

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host                    URL
41  302     HTTP        192.168.12.160:8080     /<project folder name>/images/favicon.ico
```

Would appreciate if any kind soul can help/advise on this... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the problem which is due to some configuration in **web.xml** which block the favicon from being display.

Comment: Can you be more specific, OP why you marked this as answer? e.g. What did you change in web.xml?

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried this:

href="http://domain.com/images/favicon.ico"

OR

href="http://domain.com/favicon.ico"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I can only deploy the favicon.ico within the project folder.